# How can hide the opened child windows from taskbar (WPF)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can hide the opened child windows from taskbar when I am showing and hiding the child windows even when I hide the child window the hidden window still appear in the taskbar WPF?

Thanks in advance,
Here is an Example how I show the dialogs:

```
AlignLocalAxisView alignLocalAxisView = Container.Resolve<AlignLocalAxisView>
    (new ParameterOverride("model", AttributesSelectedItems));
OpenedWindowView = alignLocalAxisView;
alignLocalAxisView.Show();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There should be a `ShowInTaskbar` property for the window.

If your window is defined in XAML, you can set the property deliberately as shown below:

```xml
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" Width="425" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False">
```

You can also set this in your code behind:

```cs
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

This is also applciable to a window created in code behind when called by name.

```cs
    Window myNewWindow = new Window();

    //Set the property to keep the window hidden in the task bar
    myNewWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    //Then, show the window
    myNewWindow.Show();
```

EDIT: Based on your example code, the following should work

```cs
    AlignLocalAxisView alignLocalAxisView = Container.Resolve<AlignLocalAxisView>(new ParameterOverride("model", AttributesSelectedItems));

    OpenedWindowView = alignLocalAxisView;

    //Assuming your view extends the Window class, the following will work
    alignLocalAxisView.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    alignLocalAxisView.Show();
```

Hopefully, this will be enough to sort the problem out.

For future reference though, this was a fairly quick solution to look up on google - its generally worth searching for an answer first as it can sometimes be a faster way to solve the problem.

in this case, I reworded your issue to "hide task bar icon for window in wpf". The child window part wasn't really needed in the search, as all windows in WPF are basically the same.

I hope that's of some help.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this way and it didn't work with me.

Comment: Can you post some example code please? This approach does work, so there is possibly something else in your code which is preventing it. It's difficult to suggest a solution without more information.

Comment: I am using MVVM and I am not using the ShowDialog method, I am using the show method to show the child windows. and they are singletons so when I am  using also Hide not close method. so the windows are being hidden rather than being collapsed.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference how you are showing the window. I fyou have a child window, the window is an instance of the `Window` class. You just need to set that property on the object. Can you post the code which creates the child window?

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha If you can edit your question to include the code which shows your window, it will be easier to resolve this for you.

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha What class do your `AlignLocalAxisView` and `OpenedWindowView` extend? At some point, the view will be loaded into a child window, in which case, the containing window which the view is loaded into will need the property setting. I have added an example which might work.

Comment: Thanks mate, The AlignLocalAxisView is a UserControl and OpenedWindowView is a my base windows class the inherited from the Window class of WPF

Comment: I’m that case, set ShowInTaskbar = false on OpenedViewWindow

Comment: Okay Thanks, let me try it.

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha It would be nice to know if this answer worked, and if so, it would be nice if you accepted it as the correct answer in case other people run into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex, and I am sorry for not responding I am sorry mate that it did not work with me. greatly appreciated mate for asking.

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha That's really odd... setting that property should force the icon to be hidden. Did you manage to get this working in the end?

Comment: not really mate, and I really appreciate your efforts for help and that you are keep following up with me.